# Magento 2.1: how to remove argument and/or argument item from block?

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.1, overrides, xml

I need to remove "from - to" price in bundle product page.

So the question is how to remove item from argument?

Block is created in

> magento2/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="bundle" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Bundle::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                </item>

                <!-- start: this should be removed -->
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Bundle::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <!-- end: this should be removed -->

                <item name="bundle_option" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Bundle::product/price/selection/amount.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

other possibility is that if i could override hole catalog_product_prices.xml

I tried using method http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41296109/5870985

Answer (score 2):

You can hide **from** and **to** label using CSS

```
.page-product-bundle .product-info-price .price-label {
    display: none;
}
```

**

### OR

**

Copy below file in your theme

> /vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

Find Line no. 47

```
'display_label'     => __('From'),
```

AND
Find Line no. 65

```
'display_label'     => __('To'),
```

Remove above code.

Comment: Is that working for you ?